# Using taglib with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, taglib

I have been googling for a couple days trying to figure out how to use taglib with Qt. After I download taglib from this link (https://github.com/taglib/taglib) I have no idea what to do. Are there any tutorials online that cover how to use taglib with Qt or can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a Qt project for taglib and operated it as .dll?
taglib .pro file:

```
DEFINES+=MAKE_TAGLIB_LIB
```

Comment: No I have not done that yet. What would I need to go about doing that?

Comment: You`ll create taglib library as a dynamic one. It depends on your source files of your current taglib downloaded. Use this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx                         Just check the config part properly so the compiler can see the taglib directory correctly.

Comment: Okay and after I have the .dll file what do I need to start using the library in qt?